# Remote Desktop Connection Windows 2008 Server

Tags: windows-server-2008

I am trying to re-enable Remote Desktop Connection ability to a windows 2008 server after I accidentally disabled it. I know the IP address of the server where it is installed. How would I do this via SSH or another computer on the network. I really need to get my access back to the server admin settings.

Comment: Please be more specific about what you did to disable it.'

Comment: I was able to use remote desktop connection application and disabled it via the windows interface on the server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enable remote desktop on a machine remotely](http://serverfault.com/questions/31708/enable-remote-desktop-on-a-machine-remotely)

Answer (score 2):

See here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794832%28v=ws.10%29.aspx for how to enable it remotely via the registry.

But honestly this is a 2 second Google search...http://viewrz.com/video/google-it

Comment: I have tried that but I do not have a name of the server, only the IP address

Comment: I have done the 2 minute google search route and nothing I did try or find has fixed my issue. I have been at this for a few days now.

Comment: Use the IP instead of the name then.  Same things apply in that Technet article.  Open regedit, choose to connect to a remote network hive, enter the IP...connect....then change the registry setting.

Comment: I did that but it would not accept it. The internal ip is 192.168.0.4. Is there a specific way I have to format it?

Comment: I followed the instructions to enable RDC via the registry but it is not working for me. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @hosker An IP address is as good as a name here. If you can't connect to the IP address (perhaps because you're on a different (public?) network) you can't use this solution until/unless you can connect to the same network the machine is on (e.g. via a VPN).